# Assign values to different index positions in Numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Say I have an array

```
np.zeros((4,2))
```

I have a list of values `[4,3,2,1]`, which I want to assign to the following positions:
`[(0,0),(1,1),(2,1),(3,0)]`

How can I do that without using the for loop or flattening the array?

I can use fancy index to retrieve the value, but not to assign them.

======Update=========

Thanks to @hpaulj, I realize the bug in my original code is.

When I use `zeros_like` to initiate the array, it defaults to `int` and truncates values. Therefore, it looks like I did not assign anything!

Comment: `arr[idx[:,0], idx[:,1]] = [4,3,2,1]`, where `idx = np.array([[0,0],[1,1],[2,2],[3,1]])`?

Comment: Position `(2,2)` is out of bounds of the original array.

Comment: Yes, you can, use fancy indexing for assignment. Try `a[[0,1,2,3], [0,1,2,1]] = 4,3,2,1`.

Comment: @wim Yes, you are right. I changed the question.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use tuple indexing:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.zeros((4,2))
>>> vals = [4,3,2,1]
>>> pos = [(0,0),(1,1),(2,0),(3,1)]
>>> rows, cols = zip(*pos)
>>> a[rows, cols] = vals
>>> a
array([[ 4.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  3.],
       [ 2.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.]])
```

Comment: Yes, it works. However, it is really strange that if I initialize the a as np.zeros_like, it does not assign values!

Comment: Edit follow up: It works in a toy sample but not in my previous code. I am not sure where the bug is.

Comment: Pay attention to dtypes when using `zeros_like`.  Assigning floats to int slots truncates the values.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in 3d. Not sure if it's a bug or that I need adapt the indexing to fit 3d

Comment: what if i had an example where i want some of these to occur multiple times. so 4 appearing in 0,0 and 1,0?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a streamlined version of @wim's answer based on @hpaulj's comment. `np.transpose` automatically converts the Python list of tuples into a NumPy array and transposes it. `tuple` casts the index coordinates to tuples which works because `a[rows, cols]` is equivalent to `a[(rows, cols)]` in NumPy.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.zeros((4, 2))
vals = range(4)
indices = [(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 0), (3, 1)]
a[tuple(np.transpose(indices))] = vals
print(a)
```