# How to assign values to a numpy array as a function of index?

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, multidimensional-array

I can only find results that use tuples of coordinates to assign certain values, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41900738/assign-values-to-different-index-positions-in-numpy-array).

I want to assign values to a 2-dimensional array as a function of their coordinates. The simplest case would be to set the value of each element to their second index (e.g. x-coordinate). Such that,

```
x[0][0] = 0
x[1][0] = 0
...
x[2][0] = 0
x[0][1] = 1
x[0][2] = 2
...
```

More complex case would be to set these values to the Euclidean distance to a certain point `(x, y)`.

My current solution is to use a for-loop, which is definitely not efficient. A vectorized implementation would be nice.

My current implementation:

```
x_mask = np.zeros((256, 256))
for i in range(256):
    for j in range(256):
        x_mask[i][j] = j
```

Comment: Your simple example is trivial. For more complex cases, you should try a vectorised solution yourself and tell us where you got stuck. There's no "generalized way" to vectorise an operation. If there was, we wouldn't need programmers :).

Comment: @jpp was expecting something like a lambda expression for each position. I guess it works equally well once I have x/y coordinates as helper matrix to compute a lot of other stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can assign a range and take advantage of NumPy [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html):

```
A = np.zeros((256, 256))
A[:] = range(A.shape[1])
# or A[:] = np.arange(A.shape[1])
```

The method you choose will be dependent on the function you wish to apply.

Comment: Works perfectly. Getting Euclidean/Manhattan distance would be easy once I have the x/y coordinates too, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

[`numpy.mgrid`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.mgrid.html) seems to be the right tool for this (especially if you want both x and y).

Example copied from the documentation:

```
>>> np.mgrid[0:5,0:5]
array([[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
        [3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
        [4, 4, 4, 4, 4]],
       [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]])
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
a=[]
for i in range(4):
    b=[]
    for j in range(4):
        b.append(j)
    a.append(b)
```

Comment: ..I don't want to use for-loop as stated.